# Array indexing in Simulink

Tags: arrays, loops, while-loop, simulink

how to deal with elements of an Array A =[1 2 4 3 6 2 7 3] in simulink like A(3) = 4.
and how about returning value like A(n-1) in simulink??
thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

To address into an array in Simulink there are a few blocks you can use.

Try the [Index Vector](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/zerobased-and-onebased-indexing-with-index-vector-block.html) block which will allow you to pass the array as one input and the index as the other. The block will output the value at the specified index.